# How Add dynamically component using drag and drog angular2

Tags: typescript, angular, drag-and-drop

How To add a component Dynamically with drag and drop

this is where I try to add my component but its not working

```
    onDrop(event:DragEvent) {
        console.log("target "+ this.target);

        this.elementDrop = this.el.nativeElement;
        event.preventDefault();

//////////////
        this.resolver.resolveComponent(Div444).then((factory) => {
            this.componentRef = this.component_target.createComponent(factory);
        });
///////////
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'borderStyle', 'bridge');
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'borderColor', 'white');
        console.log("is dropped !");

    }
```

I got as error this

```
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: _this.component_target.createComponent is not a 
browser_adapter.ts:78 Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: _this.component_target.createComponent is not a function
```

Comment: Do you need the `set target()` once you have the `@Input('target')`?!

Comment: Try `self.target = value;` instead of ` this.target = value;` where `let self = this;` is defined above the `set target ()`